# Can't seem to change the window background colour in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code so far for a GUI I am making in tkinter, I have attempted to change the background colour of the window but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Main Menu")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    videoButton = Button(self, text="Video Mode", font=helv18, bg="white", height=1, width=18)
    videoButton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.35, anchor=CENTER)

    timelapseButton = Button(self, text="Time-lapse Mode", font=helv18, bg="white", height=1, width=18)
    timelapseButton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)

root = Tk()

helv18 = Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')

root.config(bg='black')
root.geometry("480x320")
root.resizable(0, 0)

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're filling the window with a frame. Have you tried changing the color of the frame?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm very new to tkinter, how would I do that?

Comment: You do it the same way you do it for every widget.

Comment: Ah right. So root is the window and self is the frame? I don't really get how it is set up.